# Can you make a sprite in Unity with a tile set?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, 2.5d, tilesets

I’m making a 2.5D game, and the ground will be flat like regular 3D games, and I’ll have sprites standing up to make it 2.5D. I want to use tile sheets to do this, and I don’t want to make a million tile maps in the scene, with prefabs or otherwise, so I was wondering if there is any way to use my tileset to make a “sprite” in Unity.

If not, could you link me to some software where I can use tile sets to make a image?

Comment: `tile sheets`, `tile maps`, `tile sets` are these words mean the same thing? AFAIK 2.5D is called [isometric tilemaps](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tilemap-Isometric.html) in unity.

Comment: @shingo tile sheets and tile sets are the pictures where you can select a tile to place on a tile map